# How to escape space characters in golang GET request

Tags: http, go

I want to send a text string in get request using net/http package in golang. But I'm unable to find out how to do that. Like I want to hit the following url:

```
"http://api.example.com/tutor?message=how can I do this"
```

Please let me know how can I do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use this:

```
resp, err := http.Get("http://api.example.com/tutor?message=" + url.QueryEscape("how can I do this"))
```

Where `url` the [net/url package](http://godoc.org/net/url).

If you have multiple query parameters, you can use

```
p := url.Values{"message": {"hown ca I do this"}, "other": "whatever"}
resp, err := http.Get(`http://api.example.com/tutor?` + p.Encode())
```